# Angular input component duplicate ids

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm creating a component for a toggle button. The styling is dependant on the input label, so I need to use `id` and `for`.

If I have multiple of these components on the page it will clearly mess up... What's the best way to deal with this? Random generate `id` through a function?

```
<div class="toggle-group checkbox-group-inline btn btn-link">
  <input class="tgl tgl-light" id="toggle" type="checkbox" [checked]="value" (change)="stateChange($event.target.checked)">
  <label class="tgl-btn" for="toggle"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Personally I do not like to user random for unique values, even if the chances are 0.0000000000001% on failure. The question is if these checkboxes are hardcoded or generated?

Comment: @ThomasVanderVeen generated

Answer (score 1):

Use index on for:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" class="toggle-group checkbox-group-inline btn btn-link">
  <input class="tgl tgl-light" id="toggle_{{i}}" type="checkbox" [checked]="value" (change)="stateChange($event.target.checked)">
  <label class="tgl-btn" for="toggle_{{i}}"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you see a for loop?

Comment: i think he not hardcoded the checkboxes because if not, he would not have this problem with the id's, he could hardcode the id's too.

Comment: True, however some people do not have that knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a valid use case for a dynamic `id`s, as the correct way to associate `label`s with `input`s is through `id`s.

To do so, add a `randNum` property to your class that contains a random number created on instantiation. Then, you can use this random number throughout your template to create unique identifiers like so:

**Random Number** (class property)

```
randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000);
```

**Template**

```
<div class="toggle-group checkbox-group-inline btn btn-link">
  <input class="tgl tgl-light" [id]="'toggle' + randNum" type="checkbox" [checked]="value" (change)="stateChange($event.target.checked)">
  <label class="tgl-btn" [for]="'toggle' + randNum"></label>
</div>
```

Now, if you have this component 10 times on the same page, those 10 instantiations of your component will have unique values of `randNum`, producing the desired effect.

**Edit:**

If you'd rather stay away from random numbers, you can ensure uniqueness by defining a **static** property as the basis for `randNum` like so:

```
static num = CustomComponent.num || 0;
randNum = ++CustomComponent.num;
```

In the code above, each component is guaranteed to have a unique `randNum`, as it is incremented for every instantiation.